# How to run no-ip on startup -Debian

Tags: ddns

I've installed and run no-ip ddns on Kali 2.0 but when trying to get it running on startup i cant work out what to change the 'X' in rcX.d to?

The config file says:

```
If you want it to run automatically when the machine is booted, then
place the following script in your startup directory. (/etc/init.d/rcX.d
or /sbin/init.d/rcX.d or ???)

        #######################################################
        #! /bin/sh
        # . /etc/rc.d/init.d/functions  # uncomment/modify for your killproc
        case "$1" in
            start)
                echo "Starting noip2."
                /usr/local/bin/noip2
            ;;
            stop)
                echo -n "Shutting down noip2."
                killproc -TERM /usr/local/bin/noip2
            ;;
            *)
                echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop}"
                exit 1
        esac
        exit 0
        #######################################################

Where the 'X' in rcX.d is the value obtained by running the
following command
        grep initdefault /etc/inittab | awk -F: '{print $2}'
```

When i enter:

grep initdefault /etc/inittab | awk -F: '{print $2}'

i get:

`grep: /etc/inittab: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get your run level with command line :

> runlevel

[runlevel(7) | Linux man page](https://linux.die.net/man/7/runlevel)

But i think you want :

> update-rc.d .....

[update-rc.d(8) - sysv-rc | Debian Jessie Manpages](https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/sysv-rc/update-rc.d.8.en.html)

Comment: when i entered runlevel in terminal i got N 5. Does this mean that i change rcX.d to rc4.d.

Comment: You want put your script at startup ? use update-rc.d for automatic link creation with the good runlevel.

Comment: chmod 755 /etc/init.d/helloworld && update-rc.d helloworld defaults

Comment: it is NOT a recommended distribution if you’re unfamiliar with Linux or are looking for a general-purpose Linux desktop distribution for development, web design, gaming, etc.  https://docs.kali.org/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux

Comment: No - the instructions for getting the no-ip ddns tool to run on startup instructed me to add the script to /etc/init.d/ then rename the file based on the run level. The command they gave to do this (grep initdefault /etc/inittab | awk -F: '{print $2}') didnt work on Kali. With your help i can now find my run level but am not sure how to use the (N 5) run level info to rename the file. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Exactly what the update-rc.D command does....

Comment: if i understand correctly - i got to the /etc/init.d directory and run the command: update-rc.d. This then updates/rewrites/repermissions the script with my current run level?

Comment: Yes this is the command line: cp helloworld /etc/init.d/ && chmod 755 /etc/init.d/helloworld && update-rc.d helloworld defaults, where helloworld is your script name, after that reboot and then : service helloworld status, and show if running...

Answer (score 1):

For some reason I had issues with the accepted answer, so if this helps anyone running Debian on Raspberry Pi3, I used these instructions and they appear to work:

https://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/linux_beginner_books/debian_linux_desktop_survival_guide/No_IP.shtml